# Edge based SKPhysicsBody moves over time

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am using the following code to put a floor in my SpriteKit based game:

```
var floorNode = SKSpriteNode()
var floorBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(self.frame.minX, self.frame.minY), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.frame.maxX, self.frame.minY))
floorNode.physicsBody = floorBody
addChild(floorNode)
```

This places a floor at the bottom of the screen as expected.  However as I add more things to the scene, one end of the floor eventually sinks down and everything in the scene that is resting on it slides off into the abyss.

I am at a complete loss here since Apple's documentation says that "an edge-based body does not have mass or volume, and is unaffected by forces or impulses in the system. Edge-based bodies are used to represent volume-less boundaries or hollow spaces in your physics simulation."

Anyone else seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: If you add view.showsPhysics = true to your didMoveToView function and raise your floor by 10 points, do you see the floor tilting after adding nodes to your scene?

Comment: I already had showsPhysics enabled, but raising the floor by 10 resulted in one of the walls glitching this time.  It raised about halfway up the screen and rotated about 40 degrees.  Very strange.  I have no idea how a static body can suddenly shift like that.

Comment: Which build version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: xCode 6 Beta 5.  I wish I could try it in xCode 5 to see if it works differently there, but I wrote it in Swift.

Comment: This doesn't happen in Xcode 6 beta 6A267n.

Comment: @Scooter I am having this exact issue! Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to define floor for your scene, without adding any nodes to it:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

where `self` is your `SKScene`.

If you don't want ceiling on the scene, define `physicsBody` as this:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                                   self.frame.origin.y,
                                                   self.frame.size.width,
                                                   self.frame.size.height*5)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I wanted a scene that didn't have a ceiling in it, just two walls and a floor.  I have tried it the way you suggested as well, and the entire rect rotates and disrupts the scene.  The physics engine in SpriteKit is really acting glitchy for me.  Another issue I am running into is that when I remove a node when a collision is detected, sometimes another collision is detected on the node I just removed.  In other words didBeginContact fires a second time even though I removed the node the first time it fired.  Very strange behavior.

Comment: See my edited answer. As for other issues - they are a subjects of another question, not related to this one.

Comment: Andrey, that still has a ceiling, albeit a very tall one.  I have objects that can fly up and over the wall and then are removed from the scene.  I can't accomplish that with bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect which is why I just put a floor using edgeFromPoint: toPoint.  Either way though the scene still glitches after a time.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Scooter but you can predict how high they will fly, correct? And set appropriate height for scene's physicsBody. Make height `self.frame.size.height*150`, I believe that would be enough